# Getting Coffeescript to create a local variable in a FOR loop

Tags: coffeescript

How can I get `dealViewItem` into the scope of the FOR loop? Currently, dealViewItem is scoped outside of it, and all my event listeners are added to the last dealViewItem.

```
  for deal in dealArray
        dealViewItem = dealViewFactory.DealDetail(deal)
        dealViewItem.addEventListener 'click', ->
          dealCart.push(deal.dealId)
          dealViewItem.setAddedToCart()
          btnTakeDeals.setEnabled = true
        dealHolder.add(dealViewItem)
```

Comment: have a read of http://dailyjs.com/2012/07/23/js101-scope/   which describes javascript scoping, which coffeescript inherits, then you can see what do does and why its there as shown in Alexs answer

Comment: err, just to be explicit, javascript has no block scoping, just global and function scoping

Comment: dailyjs link is broken. Some other links - http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html and http://zef.me/blog/2843/javascript-the-scope-pitfall

Answer (score 38, accepted):

this is what the `do` keyword is for.  It will run a function immediately and any local variables with the same name as one of the arguments will be passed into it, ensuring proper closure scope.

```
for deal in dealArray
  do (deal) ->
    dealViewItem = dealViewFactory.DealDetail(deal)
    dealViewItem.addEventListener 'click', ->
      dealCart.push(deal.dealId)
      dealViewItem.setAddedToCart()
      btnTakeDeals.setEnabled = true
    dealHolder.add(dealViewItem)
```

Check out the [compiled version here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%20%20%20%20for%20deal%20in%20dealArray%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20do%20%28deal%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dealViewItem%20=%20dealViewFactory.DealDetail%28deal%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dealViewItem.addEventListener%20%27click%27,%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dealCart.push%28deal.dealId%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dealViewItem.setAddedToCart%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20btnTakeDeals.setEnabled%20=%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dealHolder.add%28dealViewItem%29)

---

`do` can also be used outside of loops for self executing functions.

```
#coffeescript
do ->
  foo = 'bar'

// javascript
(function() {
  var foo;
  return foo = bar;
})();
```